# POST request with Many-to-many relationship in Spring Data REST

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I'm trying to add a movie to MySQL database, here's my database schema:

```
Movie(id, name)
Genre(id, name)
Movie_genre(id_movie, id_genre)
```

And here's my model classes:

**Movie.ts**

```
public class Movie {

    private Short id;
    private String name;
    private List<MovieGenre> movieGenres;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    public Short getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Short id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false, length = 100)
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "movie")
    public List<MovieGenre> getMovieGenres() {
        return movieGenres;
    }

    public void setMovieGenres(List<MovieGenre> movieGenres) {
        this.movieGenres = movieGenres;
    }
}
```

**Genre.ts**

```
public class Genre {
    private Short id;
    private String name;
    private List<MovieGenre> movieGenres;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    public Short getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Short id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false, length = 15)
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "genre")
    @JsonIgnore
    public List<MovieGenre> getMovieGenres() {
        return movieGenres;
    }

    public void setMovieGenres(List<MovieGenre> movieGenres) {
        this.movieGenres = movieGenres;
    }
}
```

**MovieGenre.ts** ( that model stands for the generated table )

```
public class MovieGenre {
    private MovieGenrePK id;
    private Movie movie;
    private Genre genre;

    @EmbeddedId
    @JsonIgnore
    public MovieGenrePK getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(MovieGenrePK id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @MapsId("movieId")
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "movie_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
    @JsonIgnore
    public Movie getMovie() {
        return movie;
    }

    public void setMovie(Movie movie) {
        this.movie = movie;
    }

    @MapsId("genreId")
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "genre_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
    public Genre getGenre() {
        return genre;
    }

    public void setGenre(Genre genre) {
        this.genre = genre;
    }
}
```

and because we have composite key in the last model, we need a class for that :

```
public class MovieGenrePK implements Serializable {
    private Short movieId;
    private Short genreId;

    @Column(name = "movie_id", nullable = false)
    public Short getMovieId() {
        return movieId;
    }

    public void setMovieId(Short movieId) {
        this.movieId = movieId;
    }

    @Column(name = "genre_id", nullable = false)
    public Short getGenreId() {
        return genreId;
    }

    public void setGenreId(Short genreId) {
        this.genreId = genreId;
    }
}
```

So I'm trying to add a movie with genres by making a post request, first i made a post request for adding a movie and another one for adding a genre, that's works fine, now i need to associate a genre to a movie.
I tried the following:
I made a POST request to the following endpoint: `http://localhost:8080/api/movieGenres` with application/json header and with the following body:

```
{
    "movie": "http://localhost:8080/api/movies/6",
    "genre": "http://localhost:8080/api/genres/1"
}
```

but i got the error:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2018-08-22T21:10:30.830+0000",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "NullPointerException occurred while calling setter of com.movies.mmdbapi.model.MovieGenrePK.genreId; nested exception is org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: NullPointerException occurred while calling setter of com.movies.mmdbapi.model.MovieGenrePK.genreId",
    "path": "/api/movieGenres"
}
```

Comment: You don't need to create a class for the join table on a ManyToMany with JPA.  Here is an example https://hellokoding.com/jpa-many-to-many-relationship-mapping-example-with-spring-boot-maven-and-mysql/

Comment: @JasonWhite actually i have in the join table some additional fields, so that's why i need to add a model for the join table

Comment: What happened if you remove `@JsonIgnore` in `Movie#getMovieGenres()` and `Genre#getMovieGenres()` ?

Comment: In bidirectional relationship, it's necessary to have `@JsonIgnore` in one of the two side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to instatiate MovieGenrePK, change:

```
public class MovieGenre {
    private MovieGenrePK id;
}
```

to

```
public class MovieGenre {
    private MovieGenrePK id = new MovieGenrePK();
}
```

Comment: thank you. Now I'm getting a new error : `attempted to assign id from null one-to-one property [com.movies.mmdbapi.model.MovieGenre.movie]`